# Animated component adding-delete in a VBox

Tags: apache-flex, vbox

Is there a way to make the elements of a VBox smoothly move to their new positions when a new element is inserted or removed?

I actually need only to make them move smoothly when I remove an element. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Node's animated to a VBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426226/adding-nodes-animated-to-a-vbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without extending VBox and adding your own code to do so by overriding the addChild and removeChild functions.