# Adding Node's animated to a VBox

Tags: animation, javafx, vbox

I am looking for a solution to add node's with fade-in or flipping or any animation.
Thanks for any help.

I found the same question but without any further help here: [Animated component adding-delete in a VBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404379/animated-component-adding-delete-in-a-vbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jewelsea already mentioned, you would use Transitions.
Here is an example of how to do it for your use case :

```
public static void addFadingIn(final Node node, final Group parent) {
    final FadeTransition transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(250), node);
    transition.setFromValue(0);
    transition.setToValue(1);
    transition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_IN);
    parent.getChildren().add(node);
    transition.play();
  }

  public static void removeFadingOut(final Node node, final Group parent) {
    if (parent.getChildren().contains(node)) {
      final FadeTransition transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(250), node);
      transition.setFromValue(node.getOpacity());
      transition.setToValue(0);
      transition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_BOTH);
      transition.setOnFinished(finishHim -> {
        parent.getChildren().remove(node);
      });
      transition.play();
    }
  }
```

Or a more gerneral implementation using Java8 :

```
 public static void addAnimating(final Node node, final Group parent,
      final Supplier<Animation> animationCreator) {
    parent.getChildren().add(node);
    animationCreator.get().play();
  }

  public static void removeAnimating(final Node node, final Group parent,
      final Supplier<Animation> animationCreator) {
    if (parent.getChildren().contains(node)) {
      final Animation animation = animationCreator.get();
      animation.setOnFinished(finishHim -> {
        parent.getChildren().remove(node);
      });
      animation.play();

    }
  }
```

You can find a full example on https://gist.github.com/bugabinga/9576634

Comment: Totally perfect too! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [Transitions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAJJAGI) or a 3rd party library such as [FXExperience Canned Animations](http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/canned-animations/).

For an example of integrating an animation with a standard layout pane see this [LayoutAnimator code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828234/animation-upon-layout-changes) used in the example solution to: [Animation upon layout changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828234/animation-upon-layout-changes).  The LayoutAnimator is very generic and will work with other Panes than the FlowPane sample it is provided with (it just looks a bit cooler with the FlowPane).

Comment: Thanks! Also good for the hint which might also interest others. I already know it though.. and facing more the problem not knowing how to use it correctly..

     getChildren.add(node);

i use it to add any node to a vbox. But now, how can i add any animation to that call?

Comment: Updated answer to add a link to a more sophisticated example.